# scala.js jquery facade send data through trigger and on

Tags: scala.js

How do I send data with the scala.js jquery facade with trigger and on?

for example

```
$(dom.document).trigger("my-event", someData)

$(dom.document).on("my-event", (someData: ???) => {
   println(someData)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confess, I don't think I've ever used the data-sending version of `trigger` myself -- you should reference [the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) for details about how to use it. So this is a bit speculative, and you may need to do some experiments.

That said, on the Scala side, the signatures speak mostly for themselves:

```
def trigger(eventType:String, extraParameters:Any*):JQuery = js.native
def on(events:String, handler: js.Function2[JQueryEventObject, Any, Any]): JQuery = js.native
```

`trigger()` can take any data parameter, and it will be passed into the handler for `on()` *as* `Any`. This version of the signature for `on()` expects a `JQueryEventObject` as well. (Note, BTW, that there is also a signature for passing two data fields into `on()`. I didn't bother to write more than two out; that's an exercise for the reader if anybody ever needs it.)

Note also that, since the signature for `on()` is a bit weird, it can't use jquery-facade's `EventHandler` type, which provides magic for auto-converting Scala functions into JS ones. For example, if this handler was just receiving a `JQueryEventObject` (as most jQuery calls do), it would get turned into a JS function through this function in jquery-facade's package.scala:

```
implicit def f12EventHandler(func:scala.Function1[JQueryEventObject, Any]):EventHandler = { func:js.Function1[JQueryEventObject, Any] }
```

Since there isn't a standard one of those for the rare data-receiving version of `on()`, you have to either ascribe the type of your call manually, or write your own version of the above `implicit` for this case.

All this implies your signature above should probably be:

```
$(dom.document).on("my-event", (evt:JQueryEventObject, someData: Any) => {
   println(someData)
}:js.Function2[JQueryEventObject, Any, Any])
```

and then you should use pattern-matching to narrow `someData` to the actual expected type if you need to do something more interesting than `println`. Mind, I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Yes, this is a bit loosely-typed at the DOM interface; that's the reality of working with JS libraries that aren't designed to be strongly-typed.

Hope this helps...